# Parallel computing using multiple cores with Open-MP.

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am struggling to figure out how to parallelize this code with OpenMP, any help is appreciated. Below is the base code and a description.

In the simulation of a collection of soft particles (such as proteins in a fluid), there is a repulsive force between a pair of particles when they overlap. The goal of this assignment is to use parallel computing to accelerate the computation of these repulsive forces, using multiple cores with Open-MP.

In the force repulsion function, the particles are assumed to have unit radius. The particles are in a “simulation box” of dimensions L × L × L. The dimension L is chosen such that the volume fraction of particles is φ = 0.3. The simulation box has periodic (wrap-around) boundary conditions, which explains why we need to use the remainder function to compute the distance between two particles. If the particles overlap, i.e., the distance s between two particles is less than 2, then the repulsive force is proportional to k(2−s) where k is a force constant. The force is along the vector joining the two particles.

1. Write a program that tests the correctness of your code. This can be done by computing the correct forces and comparing them to the forces computed by your optimized code. Give evidence in your report that your program works correctly using your test program
2. How much faster is your accelerated code compared to the provided baseline code? Include timings for different problem sizes. Be sure to include a listing of your code in your report.

Code to parallelize

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

double get_walltime() {
struct timeval tp;
gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
return (double) (tp.tv_sec + tp.tv_usec*1e-6); }

void force_repulsion(int np, const double *pos, double L, double     krepulsion, double *forces)
{
int i, j;
 double posi [4]; double rvec [4];
 double s2, s, f;
 // initialize forces to zero
for (i=0; i<3*np; i++)
 forces[i] = 0.;
 // loop over all pairs
for (i=0; i<np; i++)
 {
posi[0] = pos[3*i ];
posi[1] = pos[3*i+1]; posi[2] = pos[3*i+2];
for (j=i+1; j<np; j++)
 {
// compute minimum image difference
 rvec[0] = remainder(posi[0] - pos[3*j ], L);
 rvec[1] = remainder(posi[1] - pos[3*j+1], L);
 rvec[2] = remainder(posi[2] - pos[3*j+2], L);
 s2 = rvec [0]* rvec [0] + rvec [1]* rvec [1] + rvec [2]* rvec [2];
 if (s2 < 4)
 {
 s = sqrt(s2);
 rvec[0] /= s; rvec[1] /= s;
 rvec[2] /= s;
 f = krepulsion*(2.-s);
 forces[3*i ] += f*rvec[0];
 forces[3*i+1] += f*rvec[1];
 forces[3*i+2] += f*rvec[2];
 forces[3*j ] += -f*rvec[0];
 forces[3*j+1] += -f*rvec[1];
 forces[3*j+2] += -f*rvec[2]; }
 } }
 }


 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 int i;
 int np = 100; // default number of particles
 double phi = 0.3; // volume fraction
 double krepulsion = 125.; // force constant
 double *pos; double *forces;
 double L, time0 , time1;

if (argc > 1)
np = atoi(argv[1]);

L = pow(4./3.*3.1415926536*np/phi, 1./3.);
 // generate random particle positions inside simulation box
forces = (double *) malloc(3*np*sizeof(double));
pos = (double *) malloc(3*np*sizeof(double));
for (i=0; i<3*np; i++)
  pos[i] = rand()/(double)RAND_MAX*L;
// measure execution time of this function

time0 = get_walltime ();
force_repulsion(np, pos, L, krepulsion, forces);
time1 = get_walltime ();

printf("number of particles: %d\n", np);
printf("elapsed time: %f\n", time1-time0);
free(forces);
free(pos);
return 0; }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read [how to ask homework questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) Also, format your code properly.

Comment: [This guide](https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/) is a good introduction to OpenMP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Theoretically, it would be as simple as this:

```
void force_repulsion(int np, const double *pos, double L, double krepulsion, 
 double *forces)
{

   // initialize forces to zero
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for (int i = 0; i < 3 * np; i++)
     forces[i] = 0.;
   // loop over all pairs
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for (int i = 0; i < np; i++)
   {
    double posi[4];
    double rvec[4];
    double s2, s, f;

    posi[0] = pos[3 * i];
    //...
```

Compilation:

```
g++ -fopenmp example.cc -o example
```

Note that I did not check for correctness. Make sure you won't have global variable inside the parallel for (as I updated your code..)

Comment: Thanks! That definitely worked and I see some improvements in running time :)